# SVN - Serialized hash missing terminator

Tags: windows, svn

I've been searching all day and haven't found any other solutions that fit ours or that work to fix ours.  We are running SVN 1.8 server and all was well until this morning when we started getting the 'hash missing' error.

I've run svnadmin verify on the last 400 revisions (I'm running it on the last 3000 revs now) and no problems have been reported.

I've run svnadmin recover and it apparently found nothing to recover.

Here is the error, we are running svn on a windows server as a service which has been restarted (it didn't help)

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: E200002: Serialized hash missing terminator
. Process command: svn.exe log svn://server.net/OurCode/CodeStuff -r "{2015-09-28T19:06:07Z}:{2015-09-28T20:41:36Z}" --verbose --xml

I've run the command from a command prompt as admin and can duplicate the error (on the server and on a client box).  If I change the date range to a revision range, the command runs fine.  I can also view logs in Tortoise.

We did a restore from 6 hours before the error started occurring and are now seeing the same error on the 'good' restored data.  I did a fresh checkout of the same revision that worked last night and it is giving the same error.

I don't see that my repo is 'corrupted' because verify and recover didn't find anything and I went back 30 revisions to a 'good' copy.  Are there any other reasons we might be seeing this?

Comment: http://nitinbhide.blogspot.ru/2013/09/recovering-from-corrupted-subversion.html

Comment: Finally getting back to make a note, it was never a problem with the repository being corrupted.  I don't really know what it was but when I changed to use revision numbers instead of dates in the range, it worked fine and has ever since.  Kind of scary about why/how after years, it suddenly stopped working with dates.